# Remove Netatalk "Network Trash Folder"

Tags: file-sharing

I'm sharing files with Netatalk from Ubuntu 14.04 to Mac OS X. On my macs, there is no network trash folder, however on Ubuntu there is a "Network Trash Folder" and "Temporary Items". 
Anyway to prevent these folders from getting created?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have samba installed!!!

edit the smb.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

and add these lines

```
# Veto the Apple specific files that a NetAtalk server creates
   veto files = /Network Trash Folder/Temporary Items
   ;delete veto files = yes
```

uncomment the last line if you want to delete these files or folders

restart samba

```
sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart
```

and don't forget to restart your client computer